# What is the distribution of $\frac{X_1}{X_2}$ if both $X_1$ and $X_2$ follows the Poisson Process?

Tags: probability-distributions

What is the distribution of $\frac{X_1}{X_2}$ if both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the Poisson Processes with parameters $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$ respectively? Please list the properties used too. Thanks !

Comment: Too little information...

Comment: Is conditional or division?

Comment: The distribution of the quotient of two Poisson random variables is obviously not well-defined--there is a nonzero probability that $X_1/X_2$ will either be infinite, or indeterminate of the form $0/0$.

Comment: Its Division.. Thanks

Comment: I am sorry... X1 and X2 are Poisson Processes not just RV

Comment: Try changing $X1/X2$ for $X_1/(X_2+1)$ for make more sense. Anyway the result is not going to be nice,

Answer (score 0):

$$P\left(\frac{N_1(t)}{N_2(t)}\leq x|N_2(t) \geq 1\right)=P\left(N_1(t)\leq N_2(t)x |N_2(t) \geq 1\right)=$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty P\left(N_1(t)\leq ix\right)P(N_2(t)=i |N_2(t)\geq 1)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^{[ix]} P\left(N_1(t)=j\right)P(N_2(t)=i|N_2(t)\geq 1)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{[ix]} P\left(N_1(t)=j\right)\frac{P(N_2(t)=i)}{P(N_2(t)\geq 1)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-e^{-\lambda_2t}}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{[ix]} P\left(N_1(t)=j\right)P(N_2(t)=i)$$